# Updating a Variable for Website Daily

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, visual-studio, caching

I'm new to .NET development and am building a simple display site.

I want to grab the number of unfinished orders from a database at the start of each day and display that number throughout the day:

( completed / original unfinished orders)

The number of "unfinished orders" changes throughout the day as orders are finished.  If I cache this variable, each user of the site may get a different number depending on when they run the script.

I want each user to be able to see the same original daily total and have it reset at night. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you can go about this. Probably one of the easiest options would be to store the completed date along with the order, where ever you are storing them, and simply query the store for all orders that have a completed date greater than the day before or doesn't have a completed date.

This would have the effect of counting all orders even if entries get completed today. So you will have consistent list of orders everyday unless more gets added in which case the number will go up.

Comment: There's a good lesson here about the power of maintaining good meta-data.

Comment: I was thinking of storing it again but there are  a large amount of total orders being queried and it takes about a minute to run the original query

Comment: Wow a 1 minute D: Regardless you will still want to implement something as above to start with to give you a reliable data source. You can then run it via a cache afterwords something like request => cache => data, where the value is cached on date. So that you can check the cache, if the data doesn't exist query the data source and store the result in the cache, then you just need to make sure that you flush the cache whenever a new order is added. If you dealing with a high frequency of new orders and count requests that will be a next step.